# Variable Resetting to Zero in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a program that will allow me to click two points on a graph by clicking the Equivalent Width Button, press the Ok button, and do an action with these points(eventually). My idea was to set a global variable to 1 when the equivalent width button was pressed and two points were selected. However, when the ok function is called, the variable is set back to 0. I know using global variables is kinda sloppy, but I'm no expert at tkinter or python as of yet so any solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

class mGui(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid()

        filename1 = tk.StringVar('')

        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = filename1 )
        entry1.grid(row=1, column=0)


        Button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Graph File", command = lambda: self.graph(filename1))
        Button1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)


        Button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Equivalent Width", command = lambda: self.equivalent_width())
        Button2.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        Button3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Ok", command = lambda: self.ok(equivalent_width_num))
        Button3.grid(row = 8, column = 2)

    def refreshFigure(self,wavelength_list, intensity_list):


        Data1 = {'Wavelength': wavelength_list,
                     'Intensity': intensity_list
                     }

        df = DataFrame(Data1, columns= ['Wavelength', 'Intensity'])
        df = df[['Wavelength', 'Intensity']].groupby('Wavelength').sum()

        figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(6,5), dpi=100)
        ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
        chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self)
        chart_type.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        #chart_type.mpl_connect('button_press_event', callback)

        df.plot(kind= 'line', legend=True, ax=ax)
        ax.set_title('The Title of your chart')


    def graph(self, filename):
        filename = filename.get()
        filename = str(filename)
        file_lines = open(filename, "r").read().split()
        file_length = len(file_lines)

        global wavelength_list
        global intensity_list

        wavelength_list = []
        i = 0
        while i < file_length:
            wave_length_value = file_lines[i]
            wavelength_list.append(wave_length_value)
            i = i + 2
        i = 1

        intensity_list = []
        while i < file_length:
            intensity_value = file_lines[i]
            intensity_list.append(intensity_value)
            i = i + 2

        wavelength_list = [float(i) for i in wavelength_list]
        intensity_list =  [float(i) for i in intensity_list]

        X = np.array(wavelength_list)
        Y = np.array(intensity_list)
        self.refreshFigure(X,Y)

    def equivalent_width(self):
        global equivalent_width_num

        def callback(event):
            print ("clicked at", event.xdata, event.ydata)
            ymouse = event.ydata
            xmouse = event.xdata

            y_coordinates.append(ymouse)
            x_coordinates.append(xmouse)

            if len(y_coordinates)==2:
                figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
                equivalent_width_num = 1
                print(equivalent_width_num)


        y_coordinates = []
        x_coordinates = []

        Data1 = {'Wavelength': wavelength_list,
                     'Intensity': intensity_list
                     }

        df = DataFrame(Data1, columns= ['Wavelength', 'Intensity'])
        df = df[['Wavelength', 'Intensity']].groupby('Wavelength').sum()

        figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(6,5), dpi=100)
        ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
        chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self)
        chart_type.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        cid = chart_type.mpl_connect('button_press_event', callback)

        df.plot(kind= 'line', legend=True, ax=ax)
        ax.set_title('The Title of your chart')

    def ok(self, equivalent_width_num):
        print(equivalent_width_num)
        if equivalent_width_num == 1:
            print("woah it worked")
            equivalent_width_num = 0
            print (equivalent_width_num)

app = mGui()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this. I'm not really sure why I didn't go this route before. It still uses globals so it's not a great solution but it will do for now.

```
 import tkinter as tk
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
 from pandas import DataFrame
 import numpy as np

 class mGui(tk.Tk):  

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
     tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
     container = tk.Frame(self)
     container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
     container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
     container.grid()

     filename1 = tk.StringVar('')

     entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = filename1 )
     entry1.grid(row=1, column=0)


     Button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Graph File", command = lambda: self.graph(filename1))
     Button1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)


     Button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Equivalent Width", command = lambda: self.equivalent_width())
     Button2.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

     Button3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Ok", command = lambda: self.ok())
     Button3.grid(row = 8, column = 2)



  def refreshFigure(self,wavelength_list, intensity_list):


    Data1 = {'Wavelength': wavelength_list,
                 'Intensity': intensity_list
                 }

    df = DataFrame(Data1, columns= ['Wavelength', 'Intensity'])
    df = df[['Wavelength', 'Intensity']].groupby('Wavelength').sum()

    figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(6,5), dpi=100)
    ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
    chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self)
    chart_type.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    #chart_type.mpl_connect('button_press_event', callback)

    #toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(chart_type, self)
    #toolbar.update()

    df.plot(kind= 'line', legend=True, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title('The Title of your chart')


 def graph(self, filename):
    filename = filename.get()
    filename = str(filename)
    file_lines = open(filename, "r").read().split() 
    file_length = len(file_lines) 

    global wavelength_list
    global intensity_list

    wavelength_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < file_length:  
        wave_length_value = file_lines[i]
        wavelength_list.append(wave_length_value)
        i = i + 2
    i = 1

    intensity_list = []
    while i < file_length:   
        intensity_value = file_lines[i]
        intensity_list.append(intensity_value)
        i = i + 2

    wavelength_list = [float(i) for i in wavelength_list] 
    intensity_list =  [float(i) for i in intensity_list]

    X = np.array(wavelength_list)
    Y = np.array(intensity_list)
    self.refreshFigure(X,Y)

 def equivalent_width(self):


     def callback(event):
        print ("clicked at", event.xdata, event.ydata)
        ymouse = event.ydata  
        xmouse = event.xdata

        y_coordinates.append(ymouse) 
        x_coordinates.append(xmouse)

        if len(y_coordinates)==2:   
            figure.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)

    global y_coordinates
    global equivalent_width_num
    equivalent_width_num = 1
    y_coordinates = [] 
    x_coordinates = []    

    Data1 = {'Wavelength': wavelength_list,
                 'Intensity': intensity_list
                 }

    df = DataFrame(Data1, columns= ['Wavelength', 'Intensity'])
    df = df[['Wavelength', 'Intensity']].groupby('Wavelength').sum()

    figure = plt.Figure(figsize=(6,5), dpi=100)
    ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
    chart_type = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, self)
    chart_type.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    cid = chart_type.mpl_connect('button_press_event', callback)

    df.plot(kind= 'line', legend=True, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title('The Title of your chart')




 def ok(self):
    print(y_coordinates)

    if len(y_coordinates) == 2 and equivalent_width_num == 1 :
        print("woah it worked")



app = mGui()
app.mainloop()
```